# XSLT: how to create an inline element? like span in html

Tags: html, xml, xslt

by use XSLT, I want to create a tag named "g" as an inline element. but always got a block element.

```xml
<xsl:element name="g">
    <xsl:text>asdf</xsl:text>
</xsl:element>
```

got this:

```html
some text
<g>asdf</g>some text
```

If changed tag name as "span", will get something like this:

```html
some text<span>asdf</span>some text
```

here is a reproducible example:
the xsl:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:n="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
                exclude-result-prefixes="n"
>
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/n:TEI/n:text/n:body">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="n:g">
        <xsl:element name="g">
            <xsl:attribute name="type">
                <xsl:text>gaiji</xsl:text>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="span">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">
                <xsl:text>gaiji</xsl:text>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
    <text>
        <body>
            some text<g>char</g>some text
        </body>
    </text>
</TEI>
```

the output( by saxonb-xslt,Saxon 9.1.0.8J ):

```html
<html>
   <body>some text
      <g type="gaiji">char</g><span class="gaiji">char</span>some text
   </body>
</html>
```

The difference is that the previous case (tag "g") will generate some useless spaces. (around the new tag) and will eventually display on the web page.

Is there any way to generate tag "g" as inline element like "span"?

I've tried searching the web and haven't seen a similar problem.

Comment: You could try `<xsl:output indent="yes" suppress-indentation="text"/>` if you have an XSLT 3+ processor

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], not snippets of code taken out of context.

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Comment: sorry, I added some samples.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in the way the result is being serialized. The serializer knows that `span` is an inline element, so it suppresses addition of whitespace.

This suggests that you are using the HTML serialization method to serialize something that isn't actually HTML. Perhaps you need to switch to the XML serialization method. Check your xsl:output declarations.

Also, with XSLT questions you should always tag the question with a specific XSLT version, since they are very different.

Comment: thanks, switch to XML works. But is there any way to let the serializer know that g is an inline element?

Comment: I ended up using XML, got more control, and like @michael.hor257k said 'improve the result's readability by adding some of your own whitespace to the output. '

Comment: @callmenp "is there any way to let the serializer know that g is an inline element?" No (not within the spec, anyway).

Comment: Well, not quite. In the version 3 specs there is an option suppress-indentation that allows you to suppress all indentation within particular elements, e.g. `para` elements. You would generally nominate the _parent_ of an inline element, not the inline element itself.

Answer (score 1):

The whitespace you see before the `g` element is a result of indentation performed by the serializer.

You can eliminate all such whitespace globally by adding `indent="no"` to the `xsl:output` declaration, or by changing the output method to `xml` (which makes `no` the default value for the `indent` attribute). I don't know of a method to turn it off locally for some elements only.

However, you can improve the result's readability by adding some of your own whitespace to the output. Here is an example (which also simplifies your existing code):

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xpath-default-namespace="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="html" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="/TEI">
    <html>
        <xsl:text>&#10;&#9;</xsl:text>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="g">
    <g type="gaiji">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </g>
    <span class="gaiji">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </span>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>
    <body>some text<g type="gaiji">char</g><span class="gaiji">char</span>some text</body>
</html>
```